# Restrict cell selection per section in UITableView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I want to restrict certain sections of my tableview to only allow 1 cell to be selected, as of right now all my cells can be selected regardless of the section it's in

There is a little twist however : My sections are an [array] and change dynamically depending on different variables.

My sections are themselves each, a Variable, so I can pinpoint to them programmatically like this :

```
var section1 = [NSDictionary(objects: [NSLocalizedString("Alcohol use less than 24 hours", comment:""), 2],
```

EDIT2: It's been pointed out that I could create a var containing the restriction

```
var restrictedSections: [[NSDictionary]: Bool] {return  [section1: true,section2: true,section3: true, section4: true, section4COPI: true, section5: true, section5COPI: true, section6: false, section7: false, section8: false] }
```

This cannot be referenced as an IndexPath, so no luck there... but maybe on the right path?

Some code from the tableView (simplified for StackOverflow readers) :

```
// checkmarks when tapped

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            if self.selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {

                cell.accessoryType = .none
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                self.selectedIndexPaths.remove(indexPath)

                if CrewMembersNumber == "1" {
                    if((indexPath).section == 0) {
                        self.section1score -= section1[(indexPath).row].object(forKey: "value") as! Int
                    } else if((indexPath).section == 1) {
                        self.section3score -= section3[(indexPath).row].object(forKey: "value") as! Int
                    }

                } else if CrewMembersNumber == "2" {
                    if((indexPath).section == 0) {
                        self.section1score -= section1[(indexPath).row].object(forKey: "value") as! Int
                    } else if((indexPath).section == 1) {
                        self.section2score -= section2[(indexPath).row].object(forKey: "value") as! Int
                    }
                } else if CrewMembersNumber == "3" {
                    if((indexPath).section == 0) {
                        self.section1score -= section1[(indexPath).row].object(forKey: "value") as! Int
                    } else if((indexPath).section == 1) {
                        self.section5score -= section5[(indexPath).row].object(forKey: "value") as! Int
                    }

                } else {
                    // if crewmemebernumber doest return 1-2 or 3
                    if((indexPath).section == 0) {
                        self.section1score -= section1[(indexPath).row].object(forKey: "value") as! Int
                    } else if((indexPath).section == 1) {
                        self.section4score -= section4[(indexPath).row].object(forKey: "value") as! Int
                    }

                }

            } else {
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor (red:236/255.0, green: 236/255, blue: 236/255, alpha: 1.0)
                self.selectedIndexPaths.add(indexPath)

                if CrewMembersNumber == "1" {
                    if((indexPath).section == 0) {
                        self.section1score += section1[(indexPath).row].object(forKey: "value") as! Int
                    } else if((indexPath).section == 1) {
                        self.section3score += section3[(indexPath).row].object(forKey: "value") as! Int
                    }

                } else if CrewMembersNumber == "2" {
                    if((indexPath).section == 0) {
                        self.section1score += section1[(indexPath).row].object(forKey: "value") as! Int
                    } else if((indexPath).section == 1) {
                        self.section2score += section2[(indexPath).row].object(forKey: "value") as! Int
                    }

                } else if CrewMembersNumber == "3" {
                    if((indexPath).section == 0) {
                        self.section1score += section1[(indexPath).row].object(forKey: "value") as! Int
                    } else if((indexPath).section == 1) {
                        self.section5score += section5[(indexPath).row].object(forKey: "value") as! Int
                    }
                } else {
                    // if crewmemebernumber doest return 1-2 or 3
                    if((indexPath).section == 0) {
                        self.section1score += section1[(indexPath).row].object(forKey: "value") as! Int
                    } else if((indexPath).section == 1) {
                        self.section4score += section4[(indexPath).row].object(forKey: "value") as! Int
                    }
                }
            }
            self.updateToolbarAndLabel(self.totalScore)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel!.text = self.textForIndexPath(indexPath);
        cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name:"Avenir", size:19)
        cell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none;

        if(self.selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath)) {

            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark;
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor (red:236/255.0, green: 236/255, blue: 236/255, alpha: 1.0)
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .none;
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
        return cell
 }
```

As you can see when I tap a cell it adds a value and the cell changes it's backgroundColor And adds a checkmark,

What I need to do is if there is a cell that is selected, in certain sections that only 1 can be selected, it needs to check if any cell within that section is selected and deselect it in favor of the new one the user tapped on. Right now I do not understand how to do this at all

thanks for any help

Comment: you want to save the section of the selected row, right

Comment: not really, unless that is needed for the sections that will be restricted

Comment: hm, I still dont understand 1st.

Comment: Well, I have a multiple of Sections, these Sections will appear (or not) depending on user selections before the table opens, to put simply sections names : section4; section5 and section4COPI section5COPI need to be "flagged" as restricted, I believe the best way to do this would be to create a "var" that makes a list of which of those is actually showing up in the tableview to restrict it. Unless there is another way to do this

Comment: Well, you can create a dictionary. var restrictSections: [String: Bool]. String would be the name of your section and Bool indicate whether or not it is restricted.

Comment: You could do as @Jp4Real Says or add a Tuple your sections dictionary with info like this (restricted: Bool, numberOfSelectableCells: Int) and later track if it is not exceeded that.

Comment: I've just built a var like this :     ```var restrictedSections: [[NSDictionary]: Bool] {return  [section1: true,section2: true,section3: true, section4: true, section4COPI: true, section5: true, section5COPI: true, section6: false, section7: false, section8: false] }```  it doesn't read anything as I can't reference it properly as IndexPath, I'm very lost

Comment: Your data model is very cumbersome and inefficient. You should use custom structs  or classes as data source array (representing the sections) which include the items representing the rows. The benefit is you can easily refer to any object just by index path. Then add a `isSelected` property to the *row* object which reflects the state of the selection  This is much more efficient and more reliably to maintain than using an extra array. For the single-selection sections get the currently selected item, set `isSelected` to `false` and in the item at index path to `true` and reload both rows.

Comment: I would love to know how to do that, that app was incredibly simple at the beginning so we didn't need that, but it evolved and different people worked on it and stuff was simply jammed in so it gave me this, it would need a huge rewrite...

Comment: Do the rewrite, it's worth it. And get rid of all that *objective-c-ish* stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundimentally the best solution (IMHO) for tableviews is to create a view model for your table, manipulate the data as required, then reflect that data in the table. Then, you do everything possible to have the table react to data changes as opposed to trying to use the table view itself to reflect data or state.

EDIT: instead of using `reloadData`, the code now uses `performBatchUpdates` for a more elegant presentation.

I created a project that does what you want and you can find it [here](https://github.com/dhoerl/TableSectionsAndAnimatedUpdate).

The view data is contained here:

```
let pilots = "Pilots"
let crew = "Crew"
let passengers = "Passengers"

var sections: [String] = []
var multipleSelectionsAllowed: Set<String> = []

var members: [String: [String]] = [:]
var selectedMembers: Set<String> = []
```

the first three string constants allow us to index into the data, and initialized:

```
sections = [pilots, crew, passengers] // initial ordering of sections
multipleSelectionsAllowed = [passengers]
```

The data is created programmatically, see the attached project or the full code attached below.

You said the sections may change, so `sections` is a variable and we'll change it later on.

`selectedMembers` contains a `hash` of the `type` (i.e. Pilot, Crew, or Passenger and their name, so it should be unique. This array will reflect the current selections, as data and not indexPaths.

But, we need indexPaths to reflect the `isSelected` UI changes: fine, we'll use two functions for this:

```
typealias KeyToValues = (section: String, name: String)

func sectionNameToHash(section: String, name: String) -> String {
    let hash = section + "|" + name
    return hash
}

func hashToSectionName(hash: String) -> KeyToValues {
    let array = hash.components(separatedBy: "|")
    assert(array.count == 2)
    return (array[0], array[1])
}
```

Also, something I've found very useful in the past is to put the code that changes the look of a cell in a single place, and call it when a cell is created or changed. You won't get out of sync over time as the UI changes too.

```
func updateCell(atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cells = tableView.visibleCells
    for cell in cells {
        guard let path = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { continue }
        if path == indexPath {
            updateCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
    }
}

func updateCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let section = sections[indexPath.section]
    guard let names = members[section] else { fatalError() }
    let name = names[indexPath.row]

    let hash = sectionNameToHash(section: section, name: name)
    let shouldBeSelected = selectedMembers.contains(hash)

    if shouldBeSelected {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        print("SELECTED", hash)
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
        print("DESELECTED", hash)
    }
}
```

You need both because in some cases you only have an indexPath, not the cell.

Note that you use the above methods when creating cells:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let section = sections[indexPath.section]
    guard let names = members[section] else { fatalError() }
    let name = names[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = name

    updateCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

When the tableView detects a selection, you will first look at the existing selected data, and first remove that selection from your data, then update any delected cell's UI:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    let section = sections[indexPath.section]
    guard let names = members[section] else { fatalError() }

    let canMultipleSelect = multipleSelectionsAllowed.contains(section)

    if !canMultipleSelect, let paths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        for path in paths {
            if path.section == indexPath.section {
                let name = names[path.row]
                let hash = sectionNameToHash(section: section, name: name)
                selectedMembers.remove(hash)
                updateCell(atIndexPath: path)
                tableView.deselectRow(at: path, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
    return indexPath
}
```

Then, handle the selection method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let section = sections[indexPath.section]
    guard let names = members[section] else { fatalError() }
    let name = names[indexPath.row]
    let hash = sectionNameToHash(section: section, name: name)

    selectedMembers.insert(hash)
    print("SELECTED THE CELL AT", hash)
    updateCell(atIndexPath: indexPath)
}
```

Voila - everything works as you want. But, even better, you can re-arrange the sections as you said you do and get everything properly selected. The example code re-arranges the sections 5 seconds after you select the first row/column

```
if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
        self.sections = [self.crew, self.pilots, self.passengers] // changed!
        tableView.reloadData()
        // all selections from the tableView are now gone
        // NOTE: none of the other data changes!
        for hash in self.selectedMembers {
            let value = self.hashToSectionName(hash: hash)
            guard
                let sectionNumber = self.sections.firstIndex(of: value.section),
                let names = self.members[value.section],
                let row = names.firstIndex(of: value.name)
            else { fatalError() }

            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: sectionNumber)
            self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
        }
    }
}
```

The reload() erases all selections, so the above code uses the known selected members to inform the tableView of list of selections, even if the cells for each are not visible.

The complete class

```
import UIKit

private final class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    override var reuseIdentifier: String? { "cell" }
}

final class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let pilots = "Pilots"
    let crew = "Crew"
    let passengers = "Passengers"

    var sections: [String] = []
    var multipleSelectionsAllowed: Set<String> = []

    var members: [String: [String]] = [:]
    var selectedMembers: Set<String> = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

        sections = [pilots, crew, passengers] // initial ordering of sections
        multipleSelectionsAllowed = [passengers]

        constructData()
    }

    private func constructData() {
        var array: [String] = []
        (1..<6).forEach { array.append("Pilot \($0)")}
        members[pilots] = array
        array.removeAll()

        (1..<20).forEach { array.append("Crew \($0)")}
        members[crew] = array
        array.removeAll()

        (1..<250).forEach { array.append("Passenger \($0)")}
        members[passengers] = array
    }

    // MARK: - Helpers -

    typealias KeyToValues = (section: String, name: String)

    func sectionNameToHash(section: String, name: String) -> String {
        let hash = section + "|" + name
        return hash
    }


    func hashToSectionName(hash: String) -> KeyToValues {
        let array = hash.components(separatedBy: "|")
        assert(array.count == 2)
        return (array[0], array[1])
    }

}

extension ViewController /*: UITableViewDataSource */ {

    override func numberOfSections(in: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let type = sections[section]
        let count = members[type]?.count ?? 0 // could use guard here too and crash if nil
        return count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let section = sections[indexPath.section]
        guard let names = members[section] else { fatalError() }
        let name = names[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = name

        updateCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func updateCell(atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cells = tableView.visibleCells
        for cell in cells {
            guard let path = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { continue }
            if path == indexPath {
                updateCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
            }
        }
    }

    func updateCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let section = sections[indexPath.section]
        guard let names = members[section] else { fatalError() }
        let name = names[indexPath.row]

        let hash = sectionNameToHash(section: section, name: name)
        let shouldBeSelected = selectedMembers.contains(hash)

        if shouldBeSelected {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            print("SELECTED", hash)
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
            print("DESELECTED", hash)
        }
    }

}

extension ViewController /* : UITableViewDelegate */ {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
        let section = sections[indexPath.section]
        guard let names = members[section] else { fatalError() }

        let canMultipleSelect = multipleSelectionsAllowed.contains(section)

        if !canMultipleSelect, let paths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
            for path in paths {
                if path.section == indexPath.section {
                    let name = names[path.row]
                    let hash = sectionNameToHash(section: section, name: name)
                    selectedMembers.remove(hash)
                    updateCell(atIndexPath: path)
                    tableView.deselectRow(at: path, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
        return indexPath
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let section = sections[indexPath.section]
        guard let names = members[section] else { fatalError() }
        let name = names[indexPath.row]
        let hash = sectionNameToHash(section: section, name: name)

        selectedMembers.insert(hash)
        print("SELECTED THE CELL AT", hash)
        updateCell(atIndexPath: indexPath)

    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
            self.sections = [self.crew, self.pilots, self.passengers]
            tableView.reloadData()
            // all selections from the tableView are gone

            for hash in self.selectedMembers {
                let value = self.hashToSectionName(hash: hash)
                guard
                    let sectionNumber = self.sections.firstIndex(of: value.section),
                    let names = self.members[value.section],
                    let row = names.firstIndex(of: value.name)
                else { fatalError() }

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: sectionNumber)
                self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
            }
        }
    }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("DESELECTED THE CELL AT", hash)

        let section = sections[indexPath.section]
        guard let names = members[section] else { fatalError() }
        let name = names[indexPath.row]
        let hash = sectionNameToHash(section: section, name: name)
        selectedMembers.remove(hash)

        updateCell(atIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, I have no words, this is amazing, I'll have to adapt it to mine the right way but it's so great, thanks a lot !

Comment: I have awarded you the bounty even if for now it doesn't work on my code since I have a lot of rewrite to do if I want this to work even remotely, but it will most certainly serve people down the road.

Comment: @Jp4Real didn’t do this just for points. Email me for help via my profile page email. Build a similar class and I will help you debug it, or review it.

Comment: not what I meant, I meant that since it answers the question and solves the problem, even tho it doesn't specifically solves mine directly (due to the complexity of the code) It will benefit the community at large and I believe you deserve the credit

Comment: Really good answer. Would be better though to put the example project to other place rather than Dropbox. Github for example. (it is usually being cleaned less often and the code overview is easier)

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov Now on GitHub: https://github.com/dhoerl/TableSectionsAndAnimatedUpdate - also replaced the reloadData() with animated deletions/insertions using performBatchUpdates.

Answer (score 0):

For number 2, You can do something like this. After deselecting you would change the `accessoryType` of that cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
  let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

  for selectedIndexPath in tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    if selectedIndexPath.section == indexPath.section {
      tableview.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
      cell?.accessoryType = .none
    }
  }

  return indexPath
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this doesn't address my issue, even if I add it to my code, simply nothing happens, the code still behaves exactly the same and keeps the checkmarks and the value up until I tap it to be deselected

Comment: You should set the accessoryType = .none after deselecting. See my edit answer

Comment: I have done that, but still no luck, I'll keep bugging around with it tomorrow, thanks for your help, but I can't accept it right now since it doesn't solve my issue, My biggest block right now is at SelectedIndexPath.section, as it doesn't. return anything

Comment: no problem. I notice you have accessoryType = .none inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath func? Should it be accesoryType = .checkmark?

Comment: when you select it a second time it has to uncheck, that's why it has both .none and .checkmark

Comment: On the fourth line, I get this : ```if selectedIndexPath.section``` : Value of type 'IndexPath.Element' (aka 'Int') has no member 'section'

Answer (score -1):

you can add one line before adding newly selected row's index path in selectedIndexPaths array

```
    self.selectedIndexPaths = self.selectedIndexPaths.filter({$0.section != indexPath.section})
    self.selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
```

when tableView gets reloaded, previously selected cell in same section will get its appearance changed due to the if else block in cellForRow.

Comment: XCode Gives me the following : "Missing argument label 'using:' in call", when I add it it adds it before '''{$0.section''' but then I get a new error : Expression type 'Bool' is ambiguous without more context which I don't fully understand

Comment: look in image ,its working fine at my end https://imgur.com/a/bALUvPC, which swift version are you using

Comment: I am using Swift 3

Comment: check out syntax in documentation and use append instead of add (idk if its your extension or what)

Comment: I declare selectedIndexPaths like this : ```var selectedIndexPaths: NSMutableArray = [] ``` do you think it could be related to that ?

Comment: well, I declared it like that "var selectedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()" , try it by declaring that way.